# VS Code - Snippets Library?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, ide, vs-code, code

Before I go through and recreate all my most commonly used snippets in VS Code, does anyone know if these have been created for apex already? ..and if so where I can find them? I have checked in the marketplace/extensions and also google but no joy.

I'm coming from Illuminated Cloud where these are all built in as live templates: 
http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/completion/livetemplates

..unfortunately InteliJ has crashed on 3 machines now so Im looking to switch to VS Code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are still looking for an extension for Apex Snippets, I have recently published one with around 41 Apex snippets.

Here is the marketplace link: [Salesforce Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajinkya-hingne.salesforce-snippets)

Currently, it only has Apex and Aura snippets but LWC snippets will be added soon.

Comment: Nice :) Thanks v much, i had already starting building my own but this is very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom code snippets in the VS Code.

Go to File -> Preference -> User Snippets in the VS Code.

You can create your own snippets there, just select the language and it will open the file.
Just put all your snippets in this format.

```
// apex.json
"apex if":{
    "prefix":"if",
    "body": [
        "if ( ${1:condition} ) {\n\t$2 \n}"
    ]
}
```

This will create code like

```
if ( condition ) {

}
```

[For more details on custom snippets.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

Additionally, for Aura and LWC and JS install [Salesforce Lightning code snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Nik-Creation.lwc-salesforce). I have been using it for months it is fantastic!

Also, there are other [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=javascript%20code%20snippets&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) available especially for Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's quite an old post, but I would like to share our Salesforce Snippets extension that contains Apex and LWC snippets.

We are adding more, and more snippets, so stay tuned :)

[Salesforce Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BeyondTheCloud.salesforce-snippets-beyondthecloud)

The whole documentation you can find [here](https://github.com/beyond-the-cloud-dev/vsc-salesforce-code-snippets).

[image]